# ASP.Net 1.1 app on IIS 7 waiting threads

Tags: .net, iis, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2, asp.net-1.1

I am running a ASP.Net 1.1 web application on windows server 2008 R2 azure web server, I note that the w3wp.exe processes always have waiting threads

can any one tell me why?

[image: .Net 1.1 w3wp.exe]